# SQL join with complicated condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

3 tables in database:

```
Supplier(id, name, address)
Product(id, name, detail)
Product_Supplier(id, productId, supplierId, quantity)
```

Now I want to get all products (which are supplied by all suppliers) and their quantity if they are supplied by supplier 1 (supplierId = 1). How can I do that in a single sql query?

Update: I can do that if use multiple queries: first I get product information from `Product` table then query `Product_Supplier` table with `productId` and `supplierId`. Do all in one query is shorter, but is it more efficient?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN will allow you to list all products, but only get the quantity for the products supplied by supplier one. You just need to use the supplierId constraint in the join condition.

```
SELECT Product.*,
       Product_Supplier.quantity
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product_Supplier ON Product.id = Product_Supplier.productId
                                       AND Product_Supplier.supplierId = 1
```

Comment: Great answer! But I have some questions. First, `left outer join` and `left join` are much different in mysql? And use multiple queries like I said and this single sql query, which is better?

Comment: @user3621203 an outer join allows the "opposite" side of the join to be null, while an inner join (normal join) does not. With an inner join you'd only get the products from supplierid = 1.  With the outer join you get all of the values in the first table, but only the quantities when it matches in the second.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm talking about `left outer join` and `left join`, not `inner join`.

Comment: @user3621203 - a left join IS an inner join, from a conceptual database perspective.  What MYSQL calls an INNER JOIN is really a cross join from a conceptual perspective.

Comment: I tried in mysql, the result of left join and left outer join are the same and differ from inner join.

Comment: MYSQL's terminology is, IMO, incorrect. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: In wiki page, `The result of a left outer join (or simply left join)`.

Comment: @user3621203 typically you'd call a left inner join just a "join" so "left outer join" and "left join" are interchangeable.  The point is that MySQL uses "inner join" incorrectly and confusingly, IMO. MSSQL's syntax is more correct in this respect.

Comment: OK, I understand your mean.